# IK leg flips Upwards

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm currently advancing my rig with IK, and ran into the problem of the leg flipping full 180 when positioning it upwards.

The First picture is showing how it wrongly flips. I of course want the leg to be positioned correctly when being posed upwards.

[image: demo picture]

Comment: possibly a wrong chain length.  check the IK constraint and make sure the chain length is set to 2.  Otherwise, please add a blend file showing the problem to your question. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: @MartyFouts The chain length is set to 2. I honestly don't want to upload the Blend file as it feels uncomfortable to do so.

Comment: You can strip the file down to just the armature and upload that.  Otherwise you haven't given enough information to help diagnose your problem.

Comment: @MartyFouts "There was an internal error attempting to complete your request"

Comment: sounds like you are using 3.x and have compression enabled.  Can you save it as a 3.0.1 or earlier file without compression?

Comment: @MartyFouts compression is deactivated and it's a 3.0.1.

Comment: I guess you've hit a bug.  Do have a Google Drive account you can put the file in and post a URL for?

Comment: You can also try adding the file to https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: did you check to see if your test rig reproduces the problem, because when I open it with 2.93.6 or 3.0.1 it seems to pose just fine.

Comment: @MartyFouts Try dragging the LeftFootControl or RightFootControl in pose mode far up.

Comment: That works, but it does remind me, in edit mode you should bend the knee a bit forward to help the IK solver know which way you want it to bend, even with a pole target.

Comment: @MartyFouts I meant really, really far up, as far as possible, like a ballerina doing that well known pose. When I drag the foot controllers that up the foot and leg 2 rotates into the wrong direction.
I made sure the knee is 0.001 forward which helps the IK solver, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, in *Edit* mode, always bend the knees a bit forward.

The *Pole Target* bone is here to make the knee bend in the right direction. If your knee is high and go further the pole target, and if you don't change the pole target position, your knee will simply rotate 180° to keep pointing towards the pole target.

So you either need to parent the pole target to the IK controller so that it will move up as well, or you need to keyframe it, so that it will always be in front of the knee:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I also thought of something like that. But this only helps to a certain degree, if I move the foot control too much up it flips again, even with the LeftLegPole set as child of the IK controller. It does follow and stuff, but it just flips again.

Comment: it is still the same problem, it's because at a certain point, even if you've parented, it may not help enough, and you'll need to keyframe the pole target, I don't think there's any way around, the IK needs to know in what direction it is supposed to bend

Comment: thank you for your help anyway.
In what way do Animators then animate really flexible acrobatic characters? Without IK or do they switch around when it's needed ? IK is meant to automate and optimize working steps. If I have to animate without them, this will get tedious very quickly.
Is there maybe another way of automatically positioning bones without IK ?

Comment: There must be a way like disable the IK and use the default settings, or keep it, but also create an IK for the thigh, and create a controller at the knee position, etc... it needs some tests

Comment: I figured it out myself on the Answer. Thank you for your support anyway :)

Comment: So what solution have you found that works for you?

Comment: Is an Answer to this question at the Top.

Comment: oh ok, fine then  ;)

Comment: "IK is meant to automate and optimize working steps" Not really. The only case where IK automates anything is when you have a chain link from point A to point B. IK will handle the inbetween chainlinks. That's it. A leg is nothing but a 2-links chain between a hip and a foot. Good rigs give animators many options to control limbs, and one of the bare minimum is to be able to switch between IK and FK and key that change though time. Ideally they also offer a way to snap between each other, as well as different location and rotation spaces for the ik controller, auto shoulder, elbow IK, ...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself.
IK without pole target, setting the knees a bit wider than needed forward. This way I can rotate with the IK controller as many spins as I want without having to rely on any poles at all.
Still, thank you all for your ideas and support, It was still very informative :)